# RabbitMQ direct reply-to. What is the queue's name

Tags: rabbitmq

If I use a RabbitMQ's direct Reply-To feature, which name of a queue I must use to peek a reply message without blocking via amqp_basic_get ?

Comment: Have you read [RabbitMQ reply-to doc](http://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html)? It has basic explanation of what's going on under the hood. In short reply-to is autogenereated queue name. You can look into client libraries (e.g., spring, php-amqp, etc) to see details, here is brief and very basic example in php - https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/master/tests/bug_gh155_direct_reply_to.phpt.

Comment: In your example a program reads a queue asynchronously via a [basic.deliver](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.deliver).
I need to read a queue in a non-blocking mode via [basic.get](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.get).
But to do this, I must somehow know on the _sender_ a name of its autogenerated temporary queue. Where can I find it?